# How can I rename an imported variable from `await` so that it does not shadow other variables?

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await, lint

Given the following code:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs';
import {promises as fsPromises} from 'fs';

// ...

// Read the file with no encoding for raw buffer access.
const { bytesRead, buffer as fileBuffer } = await fsPromises.read(fileDescriptor, allocBuffer, 0, bytes.length, 0);
```

My Typescript linter fails with: `Property 'filebuffer' does not exist on type '{ bytesRead: number; buffer: Buffer; }`

I don't like the plain `buffer` name; is there any way I can change the export with an `await` import like this?

Is the only way to add an additional line: `let fileBuffer = buffer`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `:` instead of `as` as so:

```
const { bytesRead, buffer: fileBuffer } = await fsPromises.read(handle, allocBuffer, 0, bytes.length, 0);
```